# struct.error: unpack_from requires a buffer of at least

Tags: python

Im writing a python script that is taken mostly from open source. This problem arose earlier, and I fixed it with a few simple tweaks, but now im adding onto the code (it wasnt failsafe) and im getting the same error, this time though, I dont know how to fix it. Ive gone through a ton of solutions but none match my case. Does anyone know how to add buffer or any possible ways that I could fix this error? Thanks.

> struct.error: unpack_from requires a buffer of at least 10012 bytes for unpacking 4 bytes at offset 10008 (actual buffer size is 2048).

```
import time
import struct
import operations as ops
import pyautogui as py
import Quartz.CoreGraphics as CG
from pngcanvas import PNGCanvas
from screeninfo import get_monitors

class ScreenPixel(object):

    def capture(self, region = None):

        if region is None:
            region = CG.CGRectInfinite
        else:
            if region.size.width % 2 > 0:
                emsg = "Capture region width should be even (was %s)" % (
                    region.size.width)
                raise ValueError(emsg)
            
        image = CG.CGWindowListCreateImage(
            region,
            CG.kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly,
            CG.kCGNullWindowID,
            CG.kCGWindowImageDefault)

        # Intermediate step, get pixel data as CGDataProvider
        prov = CG.CGImageGetDataProvider(image)

        # Copy data out of CGDataProvider, becomes string of bytes

        # Get width/height of image
        self.width = CG.CGImageGetWidth(image)
        self.height = CG.CGImageGetHeight(image)

        _data = CG.CGDataProviderCopyData(prov)

        return _data
    
    def save(self,_data):
            sp = ScreenPixel()

            c = PNGCanvas(sp.width, sp.height)
            for x in range(sp.width):
                for y in range(sp.height):
                    (c.point(x, y, color = sp.pixel(x,y,_data)))

            with open("test.png", "wb") as f:
                f.write(c.dump())
    
    def pixel(self, x, y, _data):

        #Must call capture first.

        data_format = "BBBB"

        offset = 4 * ((self.width*int(round(y))) + int(round(x)))

        b, g, r, a = struct.unpack_from(data_format, _data, offset=offset)

        # Return BGRA as RGBA
        return (r, g, b, a)
    
    def testLoad(self):
        sp = ScreenPixel()

        pxls = []

        region = CG.CGRectMake(20, 20, sp.height, sp.width)

        _data = sp.capture(region=region)

        rgba =  (sp.pixel(21,21,_data))

        # run save if you want to save screenshot

        #sp.save()

        return rgba
    
    def loadLoop(self):
        while True:

            rgba = self.testLoad()

            if rgba == (78,80,85,255):
                rtrn = False
                break
            
            elif rgba == (222,121,46,255):
                rtrn = True
                break
            else: pass

        rgba = None

        if rtrn == False:
            while True:
                rgba = self.testLoad2()

                print(rgba)
                if rgba == (): return True         #idk this rgba yet
                elif rgba == (): return False      #this either
                else: pass

    def testLoad2(self): 
        # a 2nd wall to ensure page has loaded
        # adds a few milliseconds but drops false loads to almost 0
        sp = ScreenPixel()

        region = CG.CGRectMake(85, 150, sp.height, sp.width)

        _data = sp.capture(region=region)

        return  (sp.pixel(86,151,_data))
```

Comment: The data you're capturing isn't big enough to hold the structure you're trying to unpack. It's hard to tell what all the parameters are when you call `pixel()`.

Comment: But the problem is that `_data` is only 2K bytes, but `offset = 4 * ((self.width*int(round(y))) + int(round(x)))` is about 10K. You obviously can't extract something from 8K after the end of the buffer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, and I now understand the problem, but how would you go about solving it @Barmar I'm really sorry if this is an obvious problem/solution. Im really new to python

Comment: also @Barmar, is there any way I can clarify what the parameters are, once calling pixel()?

Comment: It would help if you included the full traceback. It's not clear where these values are coming from, since you have multiple places that call `sp.pixel()`.